# Complexity of convolution in the max/plus ring

Tags: algebra, polynomials, fft, convolution

We can do convolution in $O(n\log n)$ for plus/multiply polynomials with FFT.  However, the approach doesn't seem very generalisable to rings in general. 
Has there been any progress over the naive $O(n^2)$ convolution for the max/plus ring?

I should note that one can transform soft-max/plus into plus/product by doing exponentiation. Here $\text{soft-max}(x,y)=\log(e^x+e^y) = \max(x,y)  + \log(1+e^{\min(x,y)-\max(x,y)})$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a more general question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10237/does-the-convolution-theorem-apply-to-weaker-algebraic-structures/), and I asked a [similar question on CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18211/maxima-of-diagonals-in-a-column-wise-and-row-wise-sorted-matrix). jbapple provided a good answer. To quote:

> ["Necklaces, Convolutions, and X+Y", By Bremner et
> al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4771) shows a
> $O\left(\frac{n^2(\lg \lg n)^3}{\lg^2 n}\right)$ algorithm
> for this problem on the real RAM and a $O(n \sqrt{n})$ algorithm in
> the nonuniform linear decision tree model.

Any improvement to this bound will shed light to a few tough open problems like sorting $X+Y$ and all pair shortest path.

If one of the functions is convex/concave, we can solve the problem in $O(n\log n)$ time. See ["Speeding up Dynamic Programming", By Eppstein et al.](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/pubs/EppGalGia-FOCS-88.pdf).

Comment: I'm wondering if "monotonically increasing" might be a useful property.

Comment: The first problem the authors tries to solve in the Necklaces paper is monotonically increasing. It's likely there is no known algorithm that performs better than the general case.